# UIViewController category not working on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm using a custom rootViewController, and am using the code below to access it from any UIViewController

```
@implementation UIViewController(CustomRootVC)

- (CustomRootVC*)customViewController
{
  UIViewController *parent = self;
  Class customClass = [CustomRootVC class];

  while ( nil != (parent = [parent parentViewController]) && ![parent customClass] )
  {
  }

  return (id)parent;
}

@end
```

If I call self.customViewController on viewDidLoad I get nil. If I call it on willAppear I get the reference I expect.

I'm guessing this is something to do with the order I add the view controllers to my view controller container (i.e. viewDidLoad is called before the view controller has been added to customViewController and so it isn't a parent), but I can't spot anything obvious. I add the view controllers as follows:

```
- (void)addViewController:(UIViewController*)controller toWrapper:(PLSliderView*)wrapper{
  [self addChildViewController:controller];
  [self addView:controller.view ToWrapper:wrapper];
  [self.viewControllers addObject:controller];
  [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

In particular, the issue seems to be with adding a new view controller and view as follows:

```
- (void)replaceTopOfStackWithViewController:(UIViewController *)newController animated:  (BOOL)animated {
  UIViewController *oldController = self.currentController;
  [self addChildViewController:newController];
  [self transitionFromViewController:oldController
                toViewController:newController
                        duration:1.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                      animations:nil
                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {                                    
                        [self.rightViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        [self removeViewController:oldController];
                        [self queryDimensions:@"REPLACE"];
                        [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                        self.currentController = newController
                      }];
```

}

Comment: just a quick question... which view controller would you like to get exactly via the `customViewController` method? According to the view controller's lifecycle, the controller is not going to the navigation stack automatically after it loads, it happens later. that is why you get `nil` value in the `–viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I am building a custom view controller container to act as a root view controller. So I'm trying to get my root controller via self.customViewController in much the same way you'd use self.navigationController

Comment: the `self.navigationController` is also `nil` until you put the controller into the stack... so, how would you like to get something at a particular time, if you already know that information will be determined later? that is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view controller hasn't been added to the view controller hierarchy at the time viewDidLoad is called, hence it has no parent view controller, hence your function returns nil as expected.

Comment: Ok, I think I've misunderstood the timeline. I had assumed that viewDidLoad was called when vc.view was first called e.g. When adding the view to a sub view or setting its frame. Is the reality that it is called when the view controller is first initialized, I.e. Before it has been added to the hierarchy.

Comment: viewDidLoad is called when vc.view is first referenced. The order of incoming methods at startup is viewDidLoad, willMoveToParentViewController, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, didMoveToParentViewController.  (I think didMove may be called earlier)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and you can verify that parentViewController is nil :)

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code `(parent = [parent parentViewController])` sets `parent` equal to `self.parentViewController`. If `self` does not have a parent view controller at the time this is called, it would return `nil` as expected.

more broadly, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this code, or why you need to use a category. it seems like that sort of behavior would make more sense in a `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: I'm basically trying to create something that acts like self.navigationController. For any UIViewController it should check its parent view controllers and return the rootViewController of class CustomRootVC

Comment: I'm building something like a splitViewController that works as the rootViewController for the app. It contains two child view controllers. Within any UIViewController I'd like to be able to use self.customViewController to push/pop/etc. new view controllers